# Why can the overriding method declare no exception when the super class method does?

Tags: java, overriding

I was going through SCJP 6 book by Kathey sierra and came across this explanations of throwing exceptions in overridden method. I quite didn't get it. Can any one explain it to me why we can't call the eat() method on Animal reference using the Dog2 object?

```
class Animal {
    public void eat() throws Exception {
        // throws an Exception
    }
}
class Dog2 extends Animal {
    public void eat() { /* no Exceptions */}
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Animal a = new Dog2();
        Dog2 d = new Dog2();
        d.eat(); // ok
        a.eat(); // compiler error - unreported exception
    }
}
```

This question might be a duplicate but the answer was not given on that question as well. Can someone explain the compiler behavior?